# Facebook for music freaks

Tags: facebook

I want to make a program which allows me to have an update on all music posted by friends, or soundcloud. My goal is to have a web page that I can see from wherever I am, with all the list, and tells me who posted what. I have heard about a query langage (FQL), do I have to use this to make my project work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Query Language is documented at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Facebook's Graph API may be simpler to use: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ (I believe FQL makes possible some things which the Graph API cannot currently do, though.)

Comment: Thank you David, I'm going to check at this. I hope I can get automated tasks (programs for school have always some required things)...

Edit: It's stupid, it's sure it allows automated tasks!